# Fill/Bind DropDownList values based upon keys

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to select/show only single group of values in `DropDownList` based upon another `DropDownList` value changed.

I have a Sync Type and **Operation Type DDL** and I want to bind/show only those key-values in Operation Type DDL whose key selected in First DDL i.e. **Sync Type DDL**.
*(Note - Values of Sync Type DDL is similar to the key of Operation Type DDL)*

Here is an Sync Type HTML markup:

```
<div>
    <label>
        Sync Type
    </label>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dllSyncType" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChannel_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Property" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Room" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Rate" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Product" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Open/Close Property" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Sync All" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

and the Operation Type DDL:

```
<div>
    <label>
        <%=Resources.Common.OperationType%>
    </label>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlOperationType">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

I am using `Dictionary` containing hard coded key-values record set to bind the values in Operation Type DDL, Like below..

```
Dictionary<string, string> dicOperationTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dicOperationTypes.Add("-1", "Select");
dicOperationTypes.Add("Property", "Check");
dicOperationTypes.Add("Property", "Open");
dicOperationTypes.Add("Property", "Close");

dicOperationTypes.Add("Room", "Activate");
dicOperationTypes.Add("Room", "Deactivate");

dicOperationTypes.Add("Rate", "Update");
dicOperationTypes.Add("Rate", "Activate");
dicOperationTypes.Add("Rate", "Deactivate");
ddlOperationType.DataSource = dicOperationTypes;
ddlOperationType.DataValueField = "Key";
ddlOperationType.DataTextField = "Value";
ddlOperationType.DataBind();
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set related data in dicOperationTypes based on the selected dllSyncType as the following code sample:

```
 public void ddlChannel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Dictionary<string, string> dicOperationTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dicOperationTypes.Add("Select", "0");
        switch (dllSyncType.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "1":
                dicOperationTypes.Add("Check", "1");
                dicOperationTypes.Add("Open", "2");
                dicOperationTypes.Add("Close", "3");
                break;
            case "2":
                dicOperationTypes.Add("Activate", "4");
                dicOperationTypes.Add("Deactivate", "5");
                break;
            case "3":
                dicOperationTypes.Add("Update", "6");
                dicOperationTypes.Add("Activate", "4");
                dicOperationTypes.Add("Deactivate", "5");
                break;
            case "4":
                // related Operation Types with Product
                break;
            case "5":
                // related Operation Types with Open/Close Property
                break;
            case "6":
                // related Operation Types with Sync All
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        ddlOperationType.DataSource = dicOperationTypes;
        ddlOperationType.DataValueField = "Value";
        ddlOperationType.DataTextField = "Key";
        ddlOperationType.DataBind();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass same key for `Dictionary<string, string>`. I think you get compile time error.

like:
    System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added.'